# Increase Playlist limit returned with Spotify iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, sdk, spotify, playlist

Does anyone have any idea how to increase the `limit` returned by the Spotify API while using the iOS SDK? I'm attempting to pull all of a users playlists but it will not let me pull more than the default 20.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if PlaylistList object has another page. If it does you then process that page too (another 20 items) and keep doing this until there are no more pages. There is a great example in this [link](https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/issues/447) .